# How to check a subregion with SIKULI

Tags: sikuli

I'm trying to use a observerinbackground to watch for some image that might apper over the region im interested.
I have an idea where this image might appear.
I've tried to create a subregion with:

```
watcher=Region(inviter)
watcher.setY(420)
watcher.setW(80)
watcher.setH(130)
```

but i have no idea if my watcher has the correct coordinates.
I need a way to verify it somehow. Some popup window or maybe a way to save it to disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the highlight method of the region class:

```
watcher.highlight(5)
```

The number is time in seconds. 
For more info on the region class visit: http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html